# Access Denied while referencing path in WebView of React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

So I am using React-native WebView for displaying local html files. I have my files located at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package/files/sample.html`. I have used React-Native-fs to write the files at this location.

Now I have a webview declared as:

`<WebView source={{uri : 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package/files/sample.html'}}/>`

So whenever I run this , the WebView shows me the page saying `net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`. If I use the React-Native-fs readfile to read the file from that path I can do it. Why am I not able to access the file path in the webView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it. `allowFileAccess` is a prop for the WebView which is set to false by default. Setting it to true allows it to access .html files from anywhere

This is what the docs say `Boolean that sets whether the WebView has access to the file system. The default value is false.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with **react-native-webview**:

> react-native-webview: We don't load your local file until we're sure the correct permissions have been set on the WebView.

[Read more about this](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/656#issuecomment-551312436)

So, on your code you have to set the url for your local file, only after the webView was loaded, here is an example how to do it:

```
const [isWebViewFinishedLoad, setIsWebViewFinishedLoad] = useState(false);

return(
   <WebView
       source={isWebViewFinishedLoad ? {uri: YOUR_LOCAL_HTML_PATH} : undefined}
       onLoadStart={() => setIsWebViewFinishedLoad(true)}

       allowFileAccess={true}
       allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}           
   />)
```

If you have a functionality that close the webView and open in again, you should reset the flag when closing the webView:

```
setIsWebViewFinishedLoad(false)
```